# Android google map How to centralize back to place

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a google map setup in app and its working perfectly. all things on google map is working as expected. My map shows the marker which contains several locations . On my Map there is a button which is used to go back to user location as I have set the following while initializing and setting up the google map :

> `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

**Now what I want:** 
In the app  , I have toolbar and in that toolbar I have a button which is supposed to act like that button. But it is taking and animating the camera in the wrong location. Below is the code I am using for doing this

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

tell me What I am doing wrong. ? and what is the way to get back to the blue spot on the map as it shows the user location ??

Please tell me what should I need to do ?

Comment: you are using locationlistener or fusedlocationprovider?

Comment: but isnt there a way to get fro google map

Comment: post your code here. how you have implemented the logic in your code.

Comment: do you have used OnMyLocationChangeListener ? the code you have posted is inside which code block ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107629/discussion-between-allay-khalil-and-sagar-nayak).